# Applications of Atiyah Singer Index Theorem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I have heard that Atiyah-Singer Index theorem has a lot of applications to the study of four manifolds. For example there is an application [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-the-Atiyah-Singer-index-theorem-What-are-some-common-applications-in-theoretical-physics). But I could not understand the answer. So it seemed to me like a very distant consequence of Atiyah-Singer Index theorem. So my question is, are there some easy interesting consequences of the index theorem. It would be great if some one could point out a good reference for the applications. Thank you.

Comment: A relatively easy consequence is Chern-Gauss-Bonnet; also the signature theorem. Is that the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Actually I have seen these consequences. I am mainly looking for applications to the theory of four manifolds in the same spirit as the answer I have given a link to.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://web.ics.upjs.sk/svoc2009/prace/5/Spacil.pdf.